# Bootstrap 4 - making centered search form take full width on small screens only

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap v.4 navbar with 3 elements in it. The elements are aligned evenly so that the search bar is centred in the navbar. When it collapses it takes full width.

This the html that I have now:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-faded">
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar5">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-stretch" id="navbar5">
    <form class="mx-2 my-auto d-inline w-100">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">GO</button>
          </span>
        </div>
    </form>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="ion-ios-gear-outline"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem here is that if I have anything less than `w-100`, the menu icon is pulled next to the search bar, and I want to it in the right corner, how can I fix that?
What I would like to do is similar to [this](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/XpNaJe?editors=1100).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sizing utils like `w-100` are not responsive. Use a column (eg. `col-md-3`) to set the width instead...

https://www.codeply.com/go/FVo4F81ShR

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Codeply</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCodeply">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarCodeply">
        <form class="mx-2 my-auto d-inline mx-auto col-md-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="...">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">GO</button>
          </span>
            </div>
        </form>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    ...
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    ...
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```